# I have a specific time as a string ("7:00 PM ET"). Can Joda-Time convert that string to the user's time zone?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm getting data on to my application and it's displaying certain events with a fixed Eastern Time zone as a string in this format: "7:00 PM ET". But I would like to know if there is a function I can use in Joda-Time to pass in a string with that format and have it output the correct time for the user's time zone. For example if I'm somewhere in central US it would output "6:00 PM". Or if I'm on the west coast, it would display "4:00 PM".

I've seen that Joda Time does have a constructor that can take a string like:

`DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( "2014-02-14T06:04:00:00", DateTimeZone.UTC );`

But that string format is not what I'm looking for.

EDIT: I will be passing the current date as well and the time will be used for that date.

Comment: The time you want to convert, does it actually occur on the date you pass in?  The current date is meaningless if the time to be converted is on a different day.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes the time will occur on the date I pass in.

Comment: This may sound like I'm being pedantic, but this type of attention to detail is required when giving specifications and asking questions.

Comment: This would be somewhat difficult to test in within your own timezone :)

Comment: @JimGarrison No you're right. I didn't think of those details.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well on my phone it's displaying with the Eastern Time Zone and I'm in Central US so it would display a different time.

Comment: I think your data will need to be `EST` or `EDT`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Date with SimpleDateFormat to achieve this although you would want to drop `ET` at the end of your time.

```
String time = "7:00 PM";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
try {
    Date date = format.parse(time);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));

    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));

    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT"));
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));

    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); // The user's timezone.
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
EST: 07:00 PM
PST: 04:00 PM
UCT: 12:00 AM
America/New_York: 07:00 PM
*/
```

It appears that you are receiving the time from EST timezone but want to convert it to the users timezone. It makes a difference to set the format timezone before parsing the time. Try this:

```
String time = "7:00 PM";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
try {
    Date date = format.parse(time);
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(format.getTimeZone().getID()+": "+format.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This might work but your answer is explicitly giving time zones, but I want to change the time by reading in the user's time zone.

Comment: This isn't working for me :/ When I call `format.parse(time)` it return a date object whose value is `Thu Jan 01 19:00:00 CST 1970`. And then after I set the timezone to `getDefault()` and then call `format.format(date)` it still outputs "7:00 PM" when it should display "6:00 PM"

Comment: Do you have more to the date than just the time of day? Well, if you are in EST then getDefault() won't change much.

Comment: I'm reading the time string from a website and I'm receiving the time in the EST timezone. But I live in a CST timezone so if the time returned from the website was "7:00 PM", then on my application it should read "6:00 PM". I also have access to a Date object with the date corresponding to the time of the event.

Comment: I called `TimeZone.getDefault.getDisplayName()` and it returned "Central Standard Time". Which is weird because it seems to be getting the right timezone, but it's not modifying the hour when I pass in the date object.

Comment: I updated my answer, the issue seems to be setting the timezone before parsing the time. Originally it would be parsing from your default timezone which is why that is happening.

Comment: Thanks man, that did it! I'm new to using all these date libraries in Java so I'm not familiar with all their uses.